# Android 11: Broadcast Receiver don't catch incomming SMS

Tags: android, sms, broadcast, receiver

My Broadcast Receiver don't work anymore, sice I have updated my tablet (Android 10 on Galaxy Tab Active 2). There was no update/change of the App. So I have no idea was is wrong now.

The Manifest is unchanged:

```
        <!-- SMS Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".services.sms.SMSReceiver_BroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

The permission is still given:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

But the broadcast receiver don'T do its job:

```
public class SMSReceiver_BroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
               Toast.makeText(context, "SMS received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   ...
```

Where is the fault?
Is a Security Update responsible, for which I have to implemend additional code?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you fixed it in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Old old question, but one of the first search results so figured I'd post an answer...

Android 11 couple things to be aware of:

- You can't make a 'toast' from a receiver anymore.  You will need to find another method for feedback - like pushing a notification, or if that is just for debugging than using the Log mechanism
- Need to add a new intent-filter action:  android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER

Comment: The `SMS_DELIVER` broadcast is only for the default SMS app. No other app will receive it.